# Table ignoring height in Grid and/or Flexbox with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-grid

So I'm making a sort of dashboard, where you can see all elements at once, so I don't want the page to scroll.

The code and codepen below show the layout of page, which it needs to adhere to. The `<table>` cannot be any taller than it is. So once the table has too many rows, it should scroll.

However, no matter where I put `.overflow-auto` or even `overflow-y: scroll` to any of `<table>`'s child elements, itself, or its parent, it will grow and fill the entire screen.

I've also seen it mentioned around that the `<table>` grows because it doesn't have a defined height, since its parent doesn't have one either. But giving each a (max-)height of 100% doesn't fix the problem either.

Is there anyway to make sure the table does not grow, while keeping everything relative (i.e. using grid/flexbox and not setting it with `px` or `rem`)?

Also, this is an internal tool that will only be used on Chrome, so there's no need for backwards compatibility.

Here's the code:

```css
/* css */
#footer {
  grid-column: 1/span 2;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3rem 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 9fr 3fr;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- html body -->
<div class="container-fluid vh-100 grid">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="d-flex" id="footer">
        <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-toggle" role="group">
            <label class="text-uppercase btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="view" type="radio"/>foobar
            </label>
            <label class="text-uppercase btn btn-secondary">
                <input name="view" type="radio"/>barfoo
            </label>
        </div>
        <!-- adding .overflow-auto to any of the-->
        <!-- below elements doesn't help-->
        <div class="flex-grow-1">
           <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
               <thead>
                   <tr>
                       <th class="sticky-top">Foo</th>
                       <th class="sticky-top">Bar</th>
                   </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                      <td>fud</td>
                      <td>baz</td>
                  </tr>
                  <!-- <tr> block repeated many more times -->
               </tbody>
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here's a sample codepen with the above code:

See the Pen 
      [Scrolling Table Problem](https://codepen.io/ABuffSeagull/pen/jONQJwv) by ABuffSeagull ([@ABuffSeagull](https://codepen.io/ABuffSeagull))
      on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Table can not scroll, but the div parent can once it reaches the value given to the grid row where it stands

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Even if I give the table's parent container a height of 100% and `overflow-y: scroll`, it still will grow and eat up the page

Comment: best is to show you i guess ;) https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dybaBLG vh-100 will work if parents have a set height (html and body ) , overflow:hidden do not allow element to grow and will allow children to show a scroll bar. give a background to sticky elements also ;) If you build this from flex, the method is the same : overflow: hidden and the child  flex:1;overflow:auto;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @G-Cyr, the fix is apparently to add an `overflow-hidden` to the `#footer` and `overflow-auto` to the `<table>`'s parent, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think in a way to fix your issue without setting values in the page :(

I started something, but I don't think is what you want: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/h1ghland3r/pen/mdbvgWB)

```
#footer
    height: 40vh

.flex-grow-1
    overflow: auto

.table thead th
    background: white
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #dee2e6
```